# How to fix 404, RealURL and Template path errors in tx_news 3.x / TYPO3 6.2 after update

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I have updated TYPO3 6.1>6.2 and tx_news 2.x > 3.x, using a "classic" setup with a separate list and detail page.

Now 
a) my templates can't be found
b) calling a detail page gives a 404 error, whenever RealURL is enabled (even if no `postVarSets` values for tx_news are set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal experiences after a few hours:

Read the changelog at  http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Changelog/3-0-0.html

**Templating:**

tx_news now features template overrides, which is great, so you don't have to clone the entire `Resources/Private` folder. But beware, the TS is different now, and there is an additional "s" in `templateRootPaths` for TS Setup, not for TS Constants (`templateRootPath`) though! (see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Templating/Start/Index.html).

The templates will kick in now. I had to use both, constants AND setup paths, though.

**RealURL and 404:**

The templates have changed largely in tx_news. One main thing is the FAL introduction.
Update the templates from scratch. Use only the templates you modified in the old version (`diff -rq` will help here).

Still, a 404 may be thrown on the detail page. It's not RealURL, it's not a pid issue, it's not the caching framework. At least in my case, it was tx_news detecting an image, but being unable to handle it, so it threw that error (see `errorHandling` on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Configuration/Reference/Index.html).

The reason was that in the extension config, `Use FAL relations instead of news media elements [records.useFal]` was set to `both`. Either set it to No - or set it to yes and re-enter the images in the FAL media field. I did the latter manually. Not sure if there's a migration assistant tool for that.